# TextCompositionEvent and PreviewTextInput

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm sending programmatically some text via InputManager to TextBox, but it does not fire PreviewTextInput before changing Text.

WPF application with on screen keyboard. In some cases (inputing currency etc.) text need to be validated before introducing to TextBox.

```
        var target = TKeyboard.FocusedElement;
        var eventArgs = new TextCompositionEventArgs(
            Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
            new TextComposition(InputManager.Current, target, text))
        {
            RoutedEvent = UIElement.TextInputEvent
        };
        InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(eventArgs);
```

I need to add text programmatically and be able to validate it before inputing into TextBox. Maybe it's not possible this way and I need different approach?

Comment: What is the issue? The event doesn't fire or text isn't changed on `ProcessInput()`?

Comment: Inputing text with TextCompositionEvent doesn't fire PreviewTextInput, so I cannot text before introducint it to the control.

Comment: See my answer, use another event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Keyboard.FocusedElement` returns the right control, then set the `Source` for the `eventArgs` to the `target` and use **`UIElement.PreviewTextInputEvent`** in `TextComposition` object. .

```
var target = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
var eventArgs = new TextCompositionEventArgs(
    Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
    new TextComposition(InputManager.Current, target, text))
{
    RoutedEvent = UIElement.PreviewTextInputEvent //   <==Use another event
};
eventArgs.Source = target; //   <==Set the Source
InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(eventArgs);
```